# JS: send http request to a specific port

Tags: javascript, url, port

I have a MERN website that uses port 80 for the front-end and port 4000 for the back-end API. In MERN tutorials, they put `axios.post('localhost:4000/login'...)` to communicate with the backend API. But this won't work in production if I have a domain like `example.com`. Is there a way to use relative URLs to specify a port, like `axios.post(':4000/login')`?

Comment: Why not `axios.post('https://example.com:4000/login'...)`?

Comment: Then I would need to set localhost or example.com in config somewhere. So is there no way to do it without setting environmental variables?

Comment: You may get `Host` header from incoming request on frontend and then send a request to backend on `(Host, Port)`

Comment: So it's the same domain as the website, just a different port? You could use something like `window.location.origin`. But the "right" way to do it is with an environment variable or some kind of config.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an axios instance like so:

```
export const myInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: backendUrl,
})
```

backendUrl should be an environment variable to your backend: https://production.com or http://localhost:4000